# Full website translate in multilingual website

Tags: i18n-l10n, 7

we are developing a multilingual site.
We have done all setting like installing Internationalizatio,Entity Translation and enabling local and content translation modules etc.

but there are some content which no get translate on choosing particular language, We want to translate my full website content on choosing particular language.
How can I perform full transable website in multilingual site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable the Content Translation module, and then, in the content type settings, set the content types to translatable. Then, you can translate content. You do that by creating translations though, in the ui, not in the interface translation ui. So, you translate content, not strings.

https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/translation

Comment: thanks, I have already done this but node's body content does not get translate. I want whole website should get translate on language basis.

Comment: It won't "get translated" by itself. You need to translate content yourself. Click buttons, copy-paste things.